# jquery not reading new dom object

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to refresh a div with new data. Before refreshing it, I'm comparing the new value which php returns with the current one. It works fine on the first refresh however from there on, it keeps using the same value that the page was initially loaded with. Here's my code

```
var someSBox = $('div#contents');
someSBoxContents  = $((someSBox).clone()).html(function(){
    $(this).find('div#a').empty();
    $(this).find('div#b').empty();
    $(this).find('div#c').removeAttr('style');
});

someSBoxContents = someSBoxContents.html();
someSBoxContents = someSBoxContents.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
response = response.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');

if (someSBoxContents === response){
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - after the page is refreshed it will always return to its initial state. Do you have a working example of the problem?

Comment: If you are calling the php via AJAX using GET request add some random number like ?rand=<currentimestamp> to avoid caching, otherwise use POST method which may not cache..... debug using google chrome network option to check what is really coming from server

Comment: the data which I get using POST is fine, it's the var someSBox = $('div#contents');
someSBoxContents  = $((someSBox).clone()).html bit that's causing the issue as it's coming back with old data (it gets the data directly from the page) - no php is involved here

Comment: div#contents, is an id selector, are you trying to assume same ID for multiple div, I request you to change the ID after cloning